# what would be an example of a function such that $\int_{|z|=r} f(z)=0$ for all $r>0$, but not analytic everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

what would be an example of a function such that $\int_{|z|=r} f(z)=0$ for all $r>0$, but not analytic everywhere.

I cannot think of one..

Comment: I'm not sure. But I think $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is an example.

Comment: @user121270 $f(z) = \frac{1}{Z^2}$ is analytic except at origin.  But we need a function which is nowhere analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=\phi(|z|)$. Then for all $r>0$
$$
\int_{|z|=r}f(z)\,dz=\phi(r)\int_{|z|=r}\,dz=0.
$$

A different example is a function $f$ analytic in $\{z\ne0\}$ and a pole at $z=0$ with residue $0$.

Comment: Would you please my edited post? I forgot to type everywhere..

Comment: How do i show that $f$ in the first example, is not analytic everywhere?

Comment: Take $\phi(r)=r^2$ for example. Then $f(z) = |z|^2$ which is nowhere complex differentiable and therefore nowhere analytic, however it is still smooth if interpreted as a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.